# Cannot catch an exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

The following code throws an `NullPointerException` that is not handled by my `try catch`. Why is that the case, and how can I handle this exception?

```
try
{
    URL url = MyTestApp.class.getResource("deliberately_bad_path/icon.png");
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Okay it was an Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Throwable  e)
{
    System.out.println("Okay it was a throwable");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So the exception is not caught and the following output is shown:

> Uncaught error fetching image:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Is it correct to use `test` instead of `url` to create image?

Comment: Sorry, I renamed some things when copying it over, its just a typo, will correct now.

Comment: Still his `catch(Exception e)` should catch the NullPointer right?

Comment: Is that the *full* stack trace? If so, the problem is likely to be that the exception isn't in your thread...

Comment: Your 2nd catch statements causes a compile error because it is not reachable. But I can reproduce the problem if I remove it. Very weird.

Comment: firstly, your catch block order is wrong, you need to catch the more specific exception before a general exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, this is the full stack trace. I did think that it maybe doing something outside of my thread. Is there anything I can do to handle this?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle apologies the posted example was a copy and paste of different things I have tried. The example has been corrected.

Comment: @AshleyMedway You can handle it by checking the intermediate values to make sure they're valid (particularly the `URL`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error cause is most likely that you passed a null Url to `Toolkit.createImage`.

The image loading is done by `sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher`. It runs in an own thread (actually it is derived from `Thread`) therefore your catch block does not catch its [error](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/image/ImageFetcher.java#191).

Comment: Good catch! If I go to the line mentionned in the stacktrace, I can see the `System.err.println("Uncaught error fetching image:");` :)

Comment: Is there anyway I could handle this?

Comment: @AshleyMedway always check that `url` is not null before passing it to `createImage`. `Class.getResource` returns null if it cannot find the resource. - therefore also check that the resource file exists.

Comment: @NathanHughes unfortunately the image fetcher does not care about UncaughtExceptionHandlers. It just does a dirty `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: and of course the whole call chain starting from `Toolkit.createImage` does not check the url argument